# Web service proxy filter implementation

Tags: web-services, proxy, filter

We are trying to create a web service proxy filter, which will be used to filter the web service call to the actual remote web service. (Spring/tomcat)

The "web service filter web service" should accept the new soap request from a web service client, filter the request based on some input data, and if data is valid it should redirect to remote web service.

Remote web service should respond back to web service client.

Ideally client should be build on using remote web service WSDL, they should just change the endpoint to the new web service filter.

create web service client from remote web service WSDL -> call filter web service proxy -> analyze input data -> redirect to remote web service -> remote web service would respond back to web service client.

Answer (score 1):

So your proxy needs to be able to parse the SOAP request to extract some 'input data'.

Yet to avoid generating Java stubs and avoid all the de-serialization processing overhead, I would implement a `javax.xml.ws.Provider<SOAPMessage>`, something like

```
@javax.xml.ws.ServiceMode(value = javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@javax.xml.ws.WebServiceProvider(
    wsdlLocation = "/mypath/my.wsdl", 
    targetNamespace = "my-namespace", 
    serviceName = "ProcessService", 
    portName = "ProcessPort"
)
public class ProcessServerRaw implements Provider<SOAPMessage> {



    public SOAPMessage invoke(final SOAPMessage request) {

//process your SOAP message object here and redirect it as is to your final SOAP web service    

    }
}
```